# vbscript error: Name Redifiined; Line 43: ExecuteGlobal sFileContents

Tags: function, vbscript, parameter-passing, call

Question from a amatuer scripter with informal coding background:

I've researched this on stack, msdn, random scripting websites but can't seem to glean a concrete solution. So please be advised this request for help is a last resort even if the solution is simple.

To put it simply, I'm trying to call a function that parses the last modified date of a file into an array of date formats. The filepath is the function parameter. These files are .vbs files in a client-side testing environment. This will be apparent if you look at the script.

My best guess is the "name redefined" error has something to do global variables being Dim'd in some way that's throwing the error.

Anyway, here's the calling sub:

```
        Option Explicit



'=============================
'===Unprocessed Report========
'=============================




'*****Inputs: File Path*********************

dim strFolderPath, strFilename, strReportName, strFileExt, FullFilePath


        strFolderPath = "C:\Users\C37745\Desktop\"
        strFilename = "UNPROCESSED_REPORT"
        strReportName = "Unprocessed"
        strFileExt = ".xlsx"




'************************************

FullFilePath = strFolderPath & strFilename & strFilename & strFileExt

'************************************





Sub Include(MyFile)
  Dim objFSO, oFileBeingReadIn  ' define Objects
  Dim sFileContents     ' define Strings

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set oFileBeingReadIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile(MyFile, 1)
  sFileContents = oFileBeingReadIn.ReadAll
  oFileBeingReadIn.Close
  ExecuteGlobal sFileContents
End Sub



Include "C:\Users\C37745\Desktop\VBStest\OtherTest\TEST_DLM.vbs"




''''''''''FOR TESTING''''''''''''''

Dim FilePath, varTEST

strFilePath = FullFilePath
varTEST = ParseDLMToArray(strFilePath)

msgbox varTESTtemp(0)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Here's the function I'm trying to call (or read, I guess):

```
        Function ParseDLMtoArray(strFilePath)

Dim strFilePath, dlmDayD, dlmMonthM, dlmYearYY, dlmYearYYYY, DateFormatArray, dateDLM
Dim objFSO, File_Object


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File_Object = objFSO.GetFile(strFilePath)
dateDLM = File_object.DateLastModified



dlmDayD = Day(dateDLM)
dlmMonthM = Month(dateDLM) 
dlmYearYY = Right(Year(dateDLM),2)
dlmYearYYYY = Year(dateDLM)



'Adds a leading zero if a 1-digit month is detected
    If(Len(Month(dlmDayD))=1) Then
          dlmmonthMM ="0"& dlmMonthM
         Else
          dlmMonthMM = dlmMonthM
    End If



'Adds a leading zero if a 1-digit day is detected
    If(Len(Day(dlmDayD))=1) Then
       dlmDayDD = "0" & dlmDayD
    Else
       dlmDayDD = dlmDayD
    End If



varDLM_mmyyyy = dlmMonthMM & dlmYearYYYY
varDLM_mmddyy = dlmMonthMM & dlmDayDD & dlmYearYY
varDLM_mmddyyyy = dlmMonthMM & dlmDayDD & dlmYearYYYY


DateFormatArray = Array( _
        varDLM_mmyyyy, _
        varDLM_mmddyy, _
        varDLM_mmddyyyy _
        )



ParseDLMtoArray = DateFormatArray



End Function
```

Any advice is appreciated, including general feedback on best practices if you see an issue there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
Function ParseDLMtoArray(strFilePath)
  Dim strFilePath 
  ...
```

tries to declare/define `strFilePath` again. That obviously can't be allowed, because it would be impossible to decide whether that variable should contain Empty (because of the Dim) or the argument you passed.

At a first glance at your code, you can just delete the `Dim strFilePath`.

Comment: Thank you sir, That was the heart of the issue (even though I found a few more typos upong further debugging). Thanks Again!